# How to control the multirow table to fit in one column?

Tags: tables, multirow

I have a multirow used in twocolumn format. The issue is that when I used some circled characters, the column of the table widened to invade the next column.

How can I control the multirow table to fit in one column?

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}
\newcommand{\round}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[anchor=south west, draw,rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=1pt, minimum size=5mm,
    text height=2mm](char){\ensuremath{#1}} ;}

\begin{document}
\centering{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Team sheet} & Node 3 & Node 7 \\    \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Time 1} 
 & Nodes & 12\circled{3}45678 & 123456\circled{7}8\\     & In &  \circled{2}\circled{4}\circled{6} & \circled{6}\circled{8} \\
      & Out & \circled{3} & \circled{7} \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Time 2} 
 & Nodes & 1\circled{2}\circled{3}\circled{4}5\circled{6}78 & 12345\circled{6}\circled{7}\circled{8}\\
      & In &  \round{1,2,3}\round{3,4,5}\round{3,6,7}& \round{3,6,7}\\
      & Out & \round{2,3,4,6} & \round{6,7,8} \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Time 3} 
 & Nodes & \circled{1}\circled{2}\circled{3}\circled{4}\circled{5}\circled{6}\circled {7}8 & 12345\circled{6}\circled{7}\circled{8}\\
      & In &  \round{2,3,4,5,6}\round{2,3,4,6}& \round{3,6,7}\\
      & Out & \round{1,2,3,4,5,6} & \round{6,7,8} \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\newpage
TeX encountered an unknown command name. You probably misspelled the
name. If this message occurs when a LaTeX command is being processed,
the command is probably in the wrong place---for example, the error
can be produced by an \verb+\item+ command that's not inside a list-making
environment. The error can also be caused by a missing \verb+\documentclass+
command.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your columns are too wide; `l`eft, `c`entre and `r`ight-aligned columns expanded *as needed* to the contents. To limit this (and allow wrapping), use a `p`aragraph column. You may also consider [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx)'s `tabularx` environment with `X`-columns.

Comment: note that `\centering` does not take an argument so `\centering{` is making the rest of the docuemnt (eg the text in column2) centred not just the table.  You could put `{\small` before the table and `}` after it, so it fits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you reduce the intercolumn whitespace a bit, to `4pt`, eliminate the whitespace to the left of the first column and the right of the final column, and get rid of all vertical column separators (which mostly add clutter), your table will fit inside the column:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{multirow,lipsum,tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}
\newcommand{\round}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]%
  \node[anchor=south west, draw,rectangle, 
     rounded corners, inner sep=1pt, minimum size=5mm,
     text height=2mm](char){\ensuremath{#1}} ;}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % reduce intercolumn whitespace

\begin{tabular}{@{} lccc @{}}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Team sheet} & Node 3 & Node 7 \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Time 1} 
 & Nodes & 12\circled{3}45678 & 123456\circled{7}8\\
 & In &  \circled{2}\circled{4}\circled{6} & \circled{6}\circled{8} \\
 & Out & \circled{3} & \circled{7} \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Time 2} 
 & Nodes & 1\circled{2}\circled{3}\circled{4}5\circled{6}78 & 12345\circled{6}\circled{7}\circled{8}\\
 & In &  \round{1,2,3}\round{3,4,5}\round{3,6,7}& \round{3,6,7}\\
 & Out & \round{2,3,4,6} & \round{6,7,8} \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Time 3} 
 & Nodes & \circled{1}\circled{2}\circled{3}\circled{4}\circled{5}\circled{6}\circled {7}8 & 12345\circled{6}\circled{7}\circled{8}\\
 & In &  \round{2,3,4,5,6}\round{2,3,4,6}& \round{3,6,7}\\
 & Out & \round{1,2,3,4,5,6} & \round{6,7,8} \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]  % filler text

\newpage
\lipsum[1]  % more filler text
\end{document}
```

---

You could further improve the look of the table by loading the `booktabs` package and use its commands `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` instead of the basic LaTeX command `\hline`. Using `booktabs`'s line-drawing commands leads to much better vertical spacing around the horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{multirow,lipsum,tikz,booktabs}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}
\newcommand{\round}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]%
  \node[anchor=south west, draw,rectangle, 
     rounded corners, inner sep=1pt, minimum size=5mm,
     text height=2mm](char){\ensuremath{#1}} ;}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % reduce intercolumn whitespace

\begin{tabular}{@{} lccc @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Team sheet} & Node 3 & Node 7 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Time 1} 
 & Nodes & 12\circled{3}45678 & 123456\circled{7}8\\
 & In &  \circled{2}\circled{4}\circled{6} & \circled{6}\circled{8} \\
 & Out & \circled{3} & \circled{7} \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Time 2} 
 & Nodes & 1\circled{2}\circled{3}\circled{4}5\circled{6}78 & 12345\circled{6}\circled{7}\circled{8}\\
 & In &  \round{1,2,3}\round{3,4,5}\round{3,6,7}& \round{3,6,7}\\
 & Out & \round{2,3,4,6} & \round{6,7,8} \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Time 3} 
 & Nodes & \circled{1}\circled{2}\circled{3}\circled{4}\circled{5}\circled{6}\circled {7}8 & 12345\circled{6}\circled{7}\circled{8}\\
 & In &  \round{2,3,4,5,6}\round{2,3,4,6}& \round{3,6,7}\\
 & Out & \round{1,2,3,4,5,6} & \round{6,7,8} \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]  % filler text

\newpage
\lipsum[1]  % more filler text
\end{document}
```